# iOS 7 taking screenshot of part of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7

I have a view (testView) that is 400x320 and I need to take a screenshot of part of this view (say rect = (50, 50, 200, 200)). 
I am playing around with the drawViewHierarchy method in iOS 7 but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.testView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.testView drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.testView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After getting the whole snapshot, you could draw it in a smaller Graphic Context in a way that you get the part you want:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(200, 200), YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(-50, -50, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**EDIT:** Better yet, draw the hierarchy directly in that smaller context:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(200, 200), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.testView drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(-50, -50, self.testView.bounds.size.width, self.testView.bounds.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: In Swift with `self.hostView.superview!.drawHierarchy(in: frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)` where `frame` is for sure smaller than the `superView`, I still get the complete view's content. But it's condensed to the `CGSize` I supplied to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` (which I of course made the same as my `frame`'s `size`).

Comment: @meaning-matters the trick here is to draw the hierarchy by using the exact same size of your view (to prevent scaling), and offset it to get the part you want.  By using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), true, 0)` you could get the top-left 200x200 part of your view with  `view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)`.  You could also offset the part your get this way: `view.drawHierarchy(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(view.bounds, UIEdgeInsets(top: -100, left: -100, bottom: 0, right: 0)), afterScreenUpdates: true)`.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code,

```
UIView *popSnapshot=[inputView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```