# How can I take snapshots for an iOS control, like UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is an unusual requirement, but let's say I have an UITableView with many UIButtons inside each UITableViewCell. What I want to achieve is to make a picture of several UIButtons(may not belong to same UITableViewCell), and I want the picture to be exactly the same as how they were presented to user.

I did try to search the apple developer library, but seems like this is unusual enough that no existing documents covers it.

I suppose at least I can get all the properties(size,font,color/image, etc) and draw it myself. But anyone know an easier way of doing this? And even if there is none and I have to draw the picture myself, where is a good place to start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to take a screenshot using `UIView`. `UIButton`, `UILabel`, etc. subclass from `UIView`

[This explains how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20558319/1040447)